# How do I import moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I would like to get the correct local time of the user on my website, but I noticed that the `new Date` constructor does not account for the timezone. I discovered **Moment.js**, which allows me to get the correct local time in the browser development console when i issue `moment().format();`, but not in my actual JavaScript file.

I have included the Moment.js file in my HTML document `<script src="js/moment-with-locales.js"></script>`, but have not imported it in my JavaScript file. How do i import the Moment.js functionality into my JavaScript file so that I can run `console.log(moment().format());` without an error?

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to load the script before your script in the html like this:

```
<head>
    <!-- The momentjs library -->
    <script src="js/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <!-- Your javascript -->
    <script src="js/my-custom-script.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then in your script you can use momentjs.

```
moment.utc('2018-01-01 23:45:55').local().format()
```

Comment: I usually put my JavaScript at the end of the ```<body>``` so the gets a head start loading before the scripts run

Comment: Looks like that did the trick. Logically, it would make sense that the Moment.js file was loaded before I tried to call it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use it directly in your HTML file, do

```
<script>
moment().format();
</script>
```

If you have to use it in a different javascript file (rendered on the browser as a script src in the app HTML), you can use include it using webpack.

Thanks
Sriram